# List GetRange in C#

Tags: c#, list

```
gridMessages.GetRange(startingRecord, rows);
```

So here's my issue, sometimes, `rows` is greater than the total amount of items left. How do I make it so, when that's the case, just get the rest of the items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gridMessages.GetRange(startingRecord, Math.Min(rows, gridMessages.Count - startingRecord));
```

Comment: Yours takes into account the starting position. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.Min().  Assuming gridMessages has a Count property; then

```
   gridMessages.GetRange(startingRecordNumber, Math.Min(rows, gridMessages.Count - startingRecordNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

gridMessages.GetRange(startingRecord, Math.Min(gridMessages.Length - startingRecord,rows))